# Bind Html.DropDownList with static items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have to bind an `Html.DropDownList` with just two items statically.

```
Text="Yes" Value="1"
Text="No"  Value="0"
```

The important thing is that, I have to set the text and value fields.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a best practice not to create the SelectList in the view. You should create it in the controller and pass it using the ViewData.

Example:

```
var list = new SelectList(new [] 
{
    new { ID = "1", Name = "name1" },
    new { ID = "2", Name = "name2" },
    new { ID = "3", Name = "name3" },
}, 
"ID", "Name", 1);

ViewData["list"]=list;
return View();
```

you pass to the constratctor: the IEnumerable objec,the value field the text field and the selected value.

in the View:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("list",ViewData["list"] as SelectList) %>
```

Comment: But how we get the selected value on post?

Comment: refer: http://www.altafkhatri.com/Technical/ASP_NET_MVC_Postback/Dropdownlist_Example/PostBack

Answer (score 37):

I used this is properly working

```
        @Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem>

                 {
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Not-Active", Value = "0" }
                 })
```

Comment: I wish this response got more upvotes. Although some may claim that it is a best practice to pass the information from the view model to the view and then back to the controller, there are certainly situations where you don't want to go through all that hassle. This approach has much less code overall, so seems like a better solution (less code = better)

Comment: Ya, seems like a better solution (less code = better)

Answer (score 5):

Code below assumes you are using razor view engine if not you will need to convert it.

```
@{
   var listItems = new List<ListItem>();
   listItems.Add(new ListItem{Text="Yes", Value="1"});
   listItems.Add(new ListItem{Text="No", Value="0"});
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedValue, listItem);
```

You should consider creating the model in your code instead of the view. Also this would be a good candidate for an editor template.

Comment: Sorry I have tried your code but it gives an error - System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Models.WorkOrder>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Thanks iaimtomisbehave for your help. Sreekumar's solution worked for me.

Comment: @Mukesh I also had the same problem, but changing the List<ListItem> to a List<SelectListItem> solved the problem (at least for me)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be alittle explicity then try

```
        @{
            var domainsList = new SelectList(new []
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".Com", Value = ".com", Selected = true },
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".Shopping", Value = ".shopping"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".Org", Value = ".org"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".Net", Value = ".net"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".AE", Value = ".ae"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = ".Info", Value = ".info"},
            }, "Value", "Text");
        }
        @Html.DropDownList("TopLevelDomains", domainsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```html
 <td>
            @{  var RlistItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

                RlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Room Type", Value = "0" });
                RlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Meeting Room", Value = "1" });
                RlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Office", Value = "2" });
                RlistItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cafeteria", Value = "3" });
            }

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.FirstOrDefault().RoomType
,RlistItems,RlistItems[item.RoomType.Value].Selected=true )
        </td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select asp-for="CountryName" asp-items=@(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem {Text="India",Value="1" } ,new SelectListItem {Text="Japan",Value="2" }} ) class="form-control">

<option>SELECT COUNTRY -- </option>
```

Comment: <select asp-for="CountryName" asp-items=@(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem {Text="India",Value="1" } ,new SelectListItem {Text="Japan",Value="2" }} ) class="form-control">

    <option>SELECT COUNTRY --</option>

</select>

Comment: A little explanation would boost the quality of your answer.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.