# Html.dropdownlist with static content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application , and on my advance search page i want to have three `html.dropdownlist` which contain static values:-

1. Exact match
2. Start With

and i need the dropdownlists to be beside any of the search field.

so can any one advice how i can create such static `html.dropdownlist`, as all the current dropdownlists which i have are bing populated with dynamic data from my model ?

Thanks

Comment: See the same question is been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576257/bind-html-dropdownlist-with-static-items

Comment: Not the same answer though, see my extension method. :) @VishalPandey I added my answer to that too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first option is to include the html within your view:

```
<select id="selection">
    <option>Exact match</option>
    <option>Starts with</option>
</select>
```

Second option is to use a hard-coded built in html helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selection", new List<SelectListItem>() {new SelectListItem { Text="Exact match", Value = "Match"}, new SelectListItem { Text="Starts With", Value = "Starts"}})
```

The third option which I would prefer if it is used a lot on your site is to create an html helper extension and you can simply use it like this:

```
@Html.SearchSelectionList()
```

Here is the code for this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SearchSelectionList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    return htmlHelper.DropDownList("selection", new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "Exact match", Value = "Match" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Starts With", Value = "Starts" } });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need the HTML-helper when only using static data?

```
<select id="myDropDownList" name="myDropDownList">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or this perhaps:

```
@{
var list = new SelectList(new []
    {
        new {ID="1", Name="volvo"},
        new {ID="2", Name="saab"},
        new {ID="3", Name="mercedes"},
        new {ID="4", Name="audi"},
    },
    "ID", "Name", 1);
}
@Html.DropDownList("list", list)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this [Bind Dropdownlist In Mvc4 Razor](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/06/bind-dropdownlist-in-mvc4-razor.html)

Let's try this way also

```
public static class DDLHelper
{
    public static IList<SelectListItem> GetGender()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> _result = new List<SelectListItem>();
        _result.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Male" });
        _result.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Female" });
        return _result;
    }
}
```

Now call static class in Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewBag.Gender = new SelectList(DDLHelper.GetGender(), "Value", "Text");
    return View();
}
```

In last now ViewBag call in view

```
@Html.DropDownList("gender", new SelectList(ViewBag.Gender, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--")
```