# Dropdownlist with unknown amount of values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist`and I would like to bind my `Dictionary`to it where the keys are the displayed items and the values are stored in the `value` attribute tag.

I found this:
[bind-html-dropdownlist-with-static-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576257/bind-html-dropdownlist-with-static-items)

But it doesn't allow for an unknown number of items to be bound as you have to manually enter the `SelectListItem`. I tried this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OverrideConfigList", new List<SelectListItem>
{
     for(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in Model.IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration)
     {
         new SelectListItem { Text = entry.Key, Value = entry.Value}
     }
})
```

But that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Edit: 
My model class looks basically like this:

```
public class DefaultConfigurationModel
{
   public IdentifiFIConfiguration IdentifiFIConfiguration { get; set; }

   public String FiKeySelection { get; set; }

   public List<String> FiConfigKeys
    {
        get
        {
            if (IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            List<string> fiConfigKeys = new List<string>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration)
            {
                fiConfigKeys.Add(entry.Key);
            }

            return fiConfigKeys;
        }
    }
}
```

`IdentifiFIConfiguration` holds `Config` which looks like this:

```
public class IdentifiConfiguration
{
    public Dictionary<String, String> Configuration { get; set; }

    public static IdentifiConfiguration DeserializeMapFromXML(string xml)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> config = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();
        configDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        foreach (XmlNode node in configDoc.SelectNodes("/xml/*"))
        {
            config[node.Name] = node.InnerText;
        }

        IdentifiConfiguration identifiConfiguration = new IdentifiConfiguration()
        {
            Configuration = config
        };

        return identifiConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the model class look like?

Comment: @FahadJameel Edited with Model

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is close, but the syntax is wrong.  You can't execute a `for` loop in a list initializer like that.

Essentially, what you're trying to do is *transform* a collection of one thing (key/value pairs) to a collection of another thing (`SelectListItem`s).  You can do that with a LINQ select:

```
Model.IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Key, Value = c.Value })
```

You may optionally need to add a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end either for static typing or to materialize the collection sooner, but that wouldn't affect the logic of the statement.

This transformation would result in the list of `SelectListItem`s that you want:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "OverrideConfigList",
    Model.IdentifiFIConfiguration.Config.Configuration.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Key, Value = c.Value })
)
```

Comment: I love you, thank you so much! This helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot bind a dropdown list to a dictionnary
you need scalar property to bind select value 
also you need a collection to bind a dropdownlist
you could do this but that ugly

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedItemValue", new SelectList(MyDictionary, "Key", "Value"))
```